# How to configure apt in Deepin 15.11 to get selected packages from other distro repos?

Tags: apt, firmware, deepin

I am using Deepin Linux 15.11 and want do install **[fwupd (LVFS)](https://fwupd.org/)** with apt / apt-get which allows firmware updates from within Linux.

Unfortunately Deepin's package repo provides a badly outdated version of fwupd :(. An uptodate version of fwupd is available on Debian buster repo. I've already added `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable` to `/etc/apt/source.list`

How do I tell apt to update **only fwupd** from debian buster instead from deepin lion?

> NOTE @admin: can you please add tags "fwupd" and "LVFS" to this post and remove this line. (I have not sufficient privileges to add new tags)

Comment: may be it can be done by adding fwupd as ppa? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/fwupd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin the package with a higher priority than the package from Debian Buster in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/fwupd`.

You can view an example [here](https://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html).